# r survival::survreg parameter estimation by formula

Tags: r

I have some difficulties understanding the use of the formula in survival::survreg. I am trying to estimate weibull parameters for different groups of data. For convenience I want to use the formula to group the data. Please consider the following code:

```
library(survival)

a <- rweibull(500, scale = 4, shape = 2)
a.ind <- rep('a', length(a))
b <- rweibull(700, scale = 6, shape = 3)
b.ind <- rep('b', length(b))

A <- data.frame(ttf = c(a,b), group = c(a.ind, b.ind))

fit <- survreg(Surv(ttf)~group, data = A, dist = "weibull")

fit.a <- survreg(Surv(a)~1, dist = "weibull")
fit.b <- survreg(Surv(b)~1, dist = "weibull")
```

My question is, why are the estimated parameters from fit different to the parameters estimated in fit.a and fit.b (e.g. coef(fit)[1] != coef(fit.a))?

Comment: This really isn't really a programming question. You really seem to have a question about how the parameters are estimated in this particular statistical model such that individual contributions are not additive. This question can probably better be answered by a statistician than a programmer. Consider posting to [stats.se] instead.

Comment: @MrFlick: Anybody who read the help pages in pkg:survival could answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fit the model, regardless of the number of groups, only one `scale` parameter is estimated. If you fix it, then the shape parameter estimates will be the same as you expect:

```
fit.scale <- survreg(Surv(ttf)~group, data = A, dist = "weibull", scale = 0.5)
fit.a.scale <- survreg(Surv(a)~1, dist = "weibull", scale = 0.5)

> coef(fit.scale)[1]
(Intercept) 
   1.376969 
> coef(fit.a.scale)
(Intercept) 
   1.376969
```

(Also note that, as documented in `?survreg.distributions`, the parameterization of the survreg Weibull distribution is different from that of `rweibull`. You can find the conversions in the examples at the bottom of `?survreg`.)